# How to have a one to one, and a many to one, relation ship EF?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-core

**Context:**

I am working with entity framework core code first approach. The entity framework core is located in .Net core class library.

**Situation:**

*Relations*

I have one table named `Question` and a table named `AnswerOption`. These tables have relationships like:

- A `Question` has one RightAnswer which is of type `AnswerOption`
- A `Question` can have more `AnswerOptions`

A question has multiple answer options and one of them is the right answer.

*Code*

```
public class Question
{
     [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
     public int Id { get; set; }

     public virtual AnswerOption RightAnswerId { get; set; }
     public virtual AnswerOption RightAnswer { get; set; }

     public virtual ICollection<AnswerOption> AnswerOptions { get; set; } 
}

public class AnswerOption
{
     [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
     public int Id { get; set; }               

     public int QuestionId { get; set; }

     public virtual Question Question { get; set; }
}
```

**Question**

When the database is created it throws the following error:

> 'Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation
>   property 'AnswerOption.Question' of type 'Question'. Either manually
>   configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the
>   '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in
>   'OnModelCreating'.'

I have try'ed to set the relation ship manually whit [entity framework relationship builder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591620(v=vs.113).aspx) in the `OnModelCreating()` method of DbContext class but don't exactly know how to get this relationship to work.

How can I declare one to one and many to one  relationships between those tables?

Comment: Why are you using this :`public virtual AnswerOption RightAnswerId { get; set; }`?

Comment: check this http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: RightAnswerId  is the Id of RightAnswer

Comment: Then it should probably be of type `int` or `string` as in the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to do that in EF Core.  AnswerOption should have a compound key for performance, and so you can enforce that the RightAnswer for a question must be one of the AnswerOptions for that question, which requires fluent config in EF Core.  Otherwise you just have to annotate the ForeignKey and InverseProperty, and make RightAnswerId nullable, so you can insert a Question without a RightAnswer.

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
//using Microsoft.Samples.EFLogging;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;


namespace EFCore2Test
{
    public class Question
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public virtual int? RightAnswerId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Id,RightAnswerId")]
        public virtual AnswerOption RightAnswer { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<AnswerOption> AnswerOptions { get; set; }
    }

    public class AnswerOption
    {       
        public int QuestionId { get; set; }

        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [InverseProperty("AnswerOptions")]
        public virtual Question Question { get; set; }
    }
    public class Db : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Question> Questions { get; set; }
        public DbSet<AnswerOption> AnswerOptions { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<AnswerOption>().HasKey(e => new { e.QuestionId, e.Id });
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=(local);Database=Test2;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true");
            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
        }
    }




    class Program
    {


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
             using (var db = new Db())
            {

                db.Database.EnsureDeleted();
               // db.ConfigureLogging(s => Console.WriteLine(s));
                db.Database.EnsureCreated();
                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                {
                    var q = new Question();
                    db.Questions.Add(q);

                    var a = new AnswerOption();
                    a.Question = q;
                    var b = new AnswerOption();
                    b.Question = q;
                    db.SaveChanges();

                    q.RightAnswer = a;
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }

            }

            Console.WriteLine("Hit any key to exit");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!!, going to try it out

Comment: I got this error any Idea why: `The relationship from ''Unable to save changes because a circular dependency was detected in the data to be saved: 'ForeignKey: Question {'Id', 'RightAnswerId'} -> AnswerOption {'QuestionId', 'Id'} ToPrincipal: RightAnswer, ForeignKey: AnswerOption {'QuestionId'} -> Question {'Id'} ToDependent: AnswerOptions ToPrincipal: Question'.'
`

Comment: Looks like you didn't configure AnswerOption to have have a compound key:  `modelBuilder.Entity<AnswerOption>().HasKey(e => new { e.QuestionId, e.Id });`

Comment: Was playing a little an just changed as you told it to be but then this error occurs (See above). There is an circular dependency between the tables.

Comment: Yes.  There's a cycle in the model.  For SQL Server this means that you have to insert the Question and AnserOptions first, then come back and set the CorrectAnswer in a subsequent command.  Updated the answer with a complete working example.